# Is there a more elegant solution to this chunk of code?

Tags: algorithm

```
var b = someObjectThatWillNotBeNull;
var a = getA();

if(a != null) {
    if(a.id == b.id) {
        functionA();
    } else {
        functionB();
    }
} else {
    functionB();
}
```

I run into this structure a lot and always need to duplicate the code where functionB is at. It just seems a little sloppy. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: This might be better suited for [codereview.SE].

Comment: WHat is the language are you using?

Answer (score 11):

```
if (a != null && a.id == b.id) {
    functionA();
} else {
    functionB();
}
```

You mean something like that?

Comment: This would throw an exception if a == null. a.id would not be instantiated. You could use a try/catch block, and instantiate in stead of else, but that's equally sloppy. .NET 4.0 added a new keyword in if statements (I think "also"?) that only continues if the first check succeeds. Depends on the language you're using.

Comment: @Corey it won't. If `a == null`, the code after the `&&` won't be evaluated.

Comment: @trutheality At least in any sane language :)

Comment: Right, I'm assuming that `&&` is a short-circuit "and" here, which is what it usually is. Is there a language where it means a non-short-circuit "and"?

Comment: I'm not aware of one, which is why I'm pretty comfortable with my answer.

Comment: You're correct, I've just been overly cautious all this time XD.

Comment: I just tried this solution out. This is actually how I originally rewrote it but I was always nervous about the if statement not checking the right side of the if statement if the left side had failed. While your solution does make sense, I guess it depends on the language you are using. I just tried this out in VB .NET 4 and it threw an error since a.id was null. (VB was not my language of choice I swear!)

Comment: @hanesjw Oh, looks like VB.NET doesn't have a `&&` at all -- it has an `And` (non-short-circuit) and an `AndAlso` (short-circuit).

Comment: @trutheality Hah! I actually just found the AndAlso keyword and that did the trick. Thanks for the help! I guess it would be nice to find a universal solution using basic operators like 'and' and 'or'. I think that is why I'm always a little reluctant to rely on the short-circuits, seems they are different in every language and it makes me nervous.

Comment: That's just silly design. I can't think of a situation in which non-short-circuiting boolean operators would be preferable, making it little more than a gotcha for anyone migrating from another language. Just my $0.02.

Comment: @jpm Non-short-circuiting operators can be convenient in some rare situations, for example, if you're iterating over a couple of lists of booleans in parallel you might want to do something like `If iter1.next() And iter2.next()`.

Comment: Fair enough, but I feel like that's such a niche that it doesn't justify defaulting to odd-ball behavior. Of course, VB has it's roots in BASIC, which has been doing things bass ackwards since before the dawn of time (or at least best-practices).

Answer (score 5):

This is a bit simpler:

```
if (a == null || a.id != b.id)
    functionB();
else
    functionA();
```

Comment: Just the flip of my answer. Personal taste, as to which is more clear. +1 all the same.

Answer (score 0):

here we are taking the advantage of && operator as 1st exp will be evaluated as true then only the next exp will be evaluated in if() statement

```
        if(a != null && a.id==b.id) {
         functionA();
        } 
        else {
        functionB();
        }
```